# How to format date?

Tags: java, datetime

Given DateTime, how to format date in the following format ?

```
12 JUL 2013
```

in c#, you do this

```
string formatedDateString = String.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy}", myDateTime);
```

What is the equivalent code in JAVA ?

Comment: Use SimpleDateFormat and specific format Strings

Comment: use jodatime http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/ to avoid headaches

Comment: What is the exact `DateTime` type? This class is not in the JDK. Or are you using `JodaTime`?

Comment: Questions about parsing and formatting dates are one of the most asked questions on StackOverflow, please search (this has been asked and answered many times before).

Answer (score 1):

And `date` represents instance of `java.util.Date`

```
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Along the lines of

```
(new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy")).parse("12 JUL 2013");
(new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy")).format(new Date());
```

Comment: He is asking about the inverse :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the localized approach as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormat.html):

```
String formattedDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date);
```